# The Applications screen freezes when I open and close the folder

Tags: 20.04, directory, screen, gnome-dash

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, the Applications screen freezes when I open and close the folder.

[image: tko]

Answer (score 2):

This problem was reported on Launchpad as [Bug #1872268 "Gnome Shell completely freezes in Ubuntu 20.04 when clicking outside of app icon folders (when ubuntu-dock is loaded)"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1872268).

In [comment #25](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1872268/comments/25), Rson explained a temporary solution

> I have this same problem. I made a video with the problem and the
>   solution here:
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3N9lnGMj-8
>
> The bug is caused by the Ubuntu Dock extension. Changing the extension
>   for the dock to not occupy the entire height of the screen solved the
>   problem.
>
> What I did to resolve it was:
>
> 1. Install dconf
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install dconf-editor
>    ```
> 2. Go to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/extend-height`
> 3. Deselect the "Use default value". And set "Custom value" to "False".