# Ubuntu freezing after Kernel update

Tags: kernel, lenovo, gnome-shell, freeze, crash

**Details of my setup:** Hardware: Thinkpad T14-Gen 2, AMD Ryzen 7 Pro graphics, 16G Ram. Software (currently): freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS, Gnome 42.9.

**Problem description:** I've been using Ubuntu (single boot) on my current machine flawlessly for 1 month. 4 days ago, I installed Wine on my computer and also did a Kernel upgrade, either of these two completely messed up the computer (I'd bet for the second). Firefox, Thunderbird, Nautilus, Terminal freezes in about 1-5 minute of use, then in 10 second the screen as well, then in 5 seconds everything. If I don't open any of these, eg. use Chrome for browsing, the computer lasts a bit longer, but still freezes in at most 15 minutes.

**My attempts:** The problem occurs both on Xorg and Wayland. I tried updating my drivers. I tried to install several Ubuntu versions (23.04, 22.04,20.04) and run them with multiple kernels.  None of these solved the problem. I ran memteset and it gave no error.  When running in recovery mode, the above-mentioned applications still crash in 5-15 minutes intervals, but the system does not.  In the log files, I see the following things reoccurring (see below):  Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 , Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" , gnome-shell crashed with sigsegv, GNOME Shell crashed with signal 11.

**Question:** How can I identify whether the problem is related to kernel or hardware or something else?

For further details regarding log files see below.

**Code example:**
before firefox crash

```
Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Sep 15 11:19:50 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a systemd[1858]: Started VTE child process 8040 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 4180.
Sep 15 11:20:22 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a rtkit-daemon[1335]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Sep 15 11:21:08 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a rtkit-daemon[1335]: message repeated 13 times: [ Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.]
Sep 15 11:21:11 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=9999 txrate=309700
Sep 15 11:21:20 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:21:22 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=9999 txrate=263200
Sep 15 11:21:31 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:21:34 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:21:43 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:21:46 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:21:55 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:21:58 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:22:07 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:22:09 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=9999 txrate=344100
Sep 15 11:22:19 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a wpa_supplicant[1028]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=309700
Sep 15 11:23:22 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a rtkit-daemon[1335]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Sep 15 11:23:25 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a rtkit-daemon[1335]: message repeated 3 times: [ Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.]
Sep 15 11:23:36 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a firefox_firefox.desktop[4276]: ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 8514
Sep 15 11:23:36 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a firefox_firefox.desktop[4276]: ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
Sep 15 11:23:36 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a firefox_firefox.desktop[8514]: ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Sep 15 11:23:36 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a kernel: [ 1517.420251] audit: type=1400 audit(1694773416.764:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/proc/4519/environ" pid=8514 comm="WRScene~ilder#1" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Sep 15 11:23:36 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a crashreporter[8515]: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Sep 15 11:23:36 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a firefox_firefox.desktop[8343]: Exiting due to channel error.
Sep 15 11:23:36 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a firefox_firefox.desktop[5223]: Exiting due to channel error.
```

other thing that occurs around crashes

```
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Sep 15 10:59:10 some1-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-2a gnome-shell[2226]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
```

**Disclaimer:** I am not an Linux expert, but I've been using Ubuntu for about 7 years now and I was able to sort all my problems with the helpful questions I see on askUbunutu and some limited programming experience. I know that there are many questions of this sort already on askUbunut, but I tried to follow up on them with no success. (See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239945/the-applications-screen-freezes-when-i-open-and-close-the-folder), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360767/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-very-often-freezes-randomly-and-does-not-recover-without-forc), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266090/why-does-my-ubuntu-20-04-computer-keep-freezing) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443251/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-freezes-few-times-per-hour-and-very-unstable?) and probably uncountably more)

Comment: Sad story, I tried installing many different linux versions and the problem remained. Finally, I solved the problem by using a Lenovo Recovery media to instlall windows. It still frooze every 10 minutes, but doing all the updates finally made the machine function well. I'm sad to let Ubuntu go, but maybe I'll come back one day:)